# Deleting and updating images on camera roll on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

in Windows Phone 8 i wish to edit an image in camera roll ( or other places ) process it and save it again.

Using the MediaLibrary SavePictureToCameraRoll() the process works except that even if I save with the same filename, it save a new copy of the image.

Is there a way to update the existing image ? Is there a way to delete an image into camera roll from code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot delete images in the media library nor you can update existing.

What you can is register your app as an image editor and then you can update image which you open directly in the photos application. There is no way for you to update image in Camera Roll programmatically.

See more on [MSDN - Photo extensibility for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202966%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).